# Inserting Date data to Mysql table using PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, mysqli

I am reading the date from android app and send it (As string) to PHP web service to insert the time to MySQL database and save it in string fields but this is not happening.The time format is DD-MM-YYYY like that 25-04-2017, Do I need to convert the date to another format.
Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
{
       require "init.php";

       creat_Student();
}
function creat_Student()
{
    global $con;  
    $user=$_POST["user_id"];
    $car=$_POST["car_id"];
    $dating=$_POST["dating"];
   ;     
    $query="Insert Into items (user_id,car_id,dating) values ('$user','$car','$dating');";
    if(mysqli_query($con,$query))
    echo $con->insert_id;
    else
      echo "Error";   
     mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Please share with us the values of the added row, I mean the end result in the DB table.

Comment: It depends what the date column structure is formatted to accept. Share the mysql schema

Comment: I added pic of database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your database column schema, generally you can string to time $dating then format as YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s or YYYY-MM-DD

DATETIME in DB Column

```
$dating = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strototime($dating));
```

OR

DATE in DB Column

```
$dating = date('Y-m-d',strototime($dating));
```

Comment: So I have to make the table field of type date?

Comment: Generally if you're doing dates within a MYSQL Database you would use date or datetime as a timestamp, it makes it easier to manipulate in the future with php etc.